# Where to store the session state?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 4 app wherein the user logs in. After the user logs in, additional data is gotten such as role, name, address etc.

Where, in an MVC app, is it typical to store this information?  In an aspx app, I would have said in the Session object.  Is that still where it should be stored?

Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Yes, you can just use `Session[]` for this.

Comment: OK, fair enough.  I guess MVC really isn't any different than aspx, just wrapped up a bit differently.

Comment: It's all about the pattern. It's the same .NET framework but organized with a different pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rely on Session to store this information. User still needs to send the Session Id on every requests, in order to get use the Session (don't know how .NET MVC handles this).

I also use the Items of HttpRequest to save data relative to the current request (the data is set on pre-request event, and consumed by looking up at Http Request Items.

Answer (score 0):

I think Session object is the way to go in this scenario. Like Web app, MVC doesn't have Viewstate but Session works the same.